# Testing autoloader using phpunit without loading classes from composer's autoloader

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php

Follow up question from [Autoloader for distributed PHP plugins that includes composer packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41954004/autoloader-for-distributed-php-plugins-that-includes-composer-packages/)

I am writing an application that publishes distributed extensions for a CMS. Think of each distributed extension as a zip that contains the extension code and all its dependencies (which are copied composer packages).

In the package, there's an autoloader that loads it's dependencies.

I am using PHPUnit to test if the dependencies are loading correctly. But when instantiating the class in the test class, the dependencies are already loaded via composer.

I execute `composer exec phpunit TestAutoloader` in the test below. **How can I write a test so that the dependency does not load from composer?**

Test code

```
class TestAutoloader extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function test_can_load_dependencies() {
        $myClass = new MyClass();

        $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($myClass->client());
        echo $reflection->getFileName(); // This is loading from vendors folder instead of uploads/dependency

        //$this->assertTrue(class_exists('GuzzleHttp\Client'));
    }
}
```

The problem illustrated

```
/upload/MyClass.php

should load

/upload/dependencies/example/src/MyDependency.php

but the test is loading from

/vendor/example/src/MyDependency.php
```

Comment: Can't you make phpunit use a bootstrap (`<phpunit bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php">`), and define your own custom autoloader in the bootstrap file (instead of it using composer by default)

Comment: This sounds plausible but wouldn't that affect all other tests? Is it possible to target this specific test?